# How to set keyword arguments values as other keyword arguments?

Tags: python, arguments, refactoring, keyword, abstraction

Is there a (clean, easy) way to set keyword args as other keyword args in a parameters list? Something like this:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, kwarg1='a', kwarg2=kwarg1, kwarg3=kwarg1):
```

I basically need all three to have the same default value without hard coding it in. That way if the user wants to edit `kwarg1`to be something else, the default of `kwarg2` and `kwarg3` will default to the new value as well; but will still allow the functionality of customizing `kwarg2` and `kwarg3` if desired.

I imagine I can do something like this:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, kwarg1='a', kwarg2='', kwarg3=''):
        if kwarg2 == '':
            self.kwarg2 = kwarg1

        if kwarg3 == '':
            self.kwarg3 = kwarg1
```

It's just kind of ugly. I know this is an odd question. Just kinda curious if there is a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Setting value `None` to `kwarg1` and `kwarg2` might help you.:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,kwarg1='a',kwarg2=None,kwarg3=None):
        self.kwarg1 = kwarg1
        self.kwarg2 = kwarg2 if kwarg2 != None else self.kwarg2 = kwarg1
        self.kwarg3 = kwarg3 if kwarg3 != None else self.kwarg3 = kwarg1
```

Comment: even more fun might be `self.kwarg2 = kwarg2 or kwarg1` (only if kwarg2 is never a falsey value)

Comment: That is pretty much perfect. I didn't know you could add if statements to variable assignments. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could splat your kwargs and use `dict.setdefault`

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('kwarg1', 'a')
        kwargs.setdefault('kwarg2', kwargs['kwarg1'])
        kwargs.setdefault('kwarg3', kwargs['kwarg1'])

        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```